# Problem with terminal and shell how to resolve?

Tags: command-line

When I run my terminal and digit `sudo su` (to access to root) the terminal says: `Cannot execute shell: No such file or directory.`

What does it mean? How can I solve my problem?

Comment: Please post the command you trying to execute.

Comment: It should be if I get you correctly `sudo digit` then enter your password to run `digit` as `root user`

Comment: @George: I think you nailed it...  Should be an answer.  After you've done that, ping me and I'll upvote!

Comment: Glad it helped just posted an answer :).

Answer (score 1):

You got your syntax wrong it aught to be:

```
sudo digit
```

Then enter your password to run `digit` as `root user`